# What is the "lang-inno" language code for?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for a syntax highlighter for the [inno-setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inno-setup) tag and I've tried (out of curiosity) to use:

```
<!-- language: lang-inno -->
```

And I was surprised that the code got highlighted (not so much correctly for [inno-setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inno-setup) scripts though), so I'm wondering, for which language is the above ([unlisted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/179541)) language code ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `lang-inno` tag, and no language highlighter is associated with it.

Unsupported tags are interpreted as `language: default` instead, overriding any specific language that might be associated with any other question tag. The default highlighter makes educated guesses, and that could end up looking reasonable.

Quoting from the [central Syntax Highlighting FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work):

> Just because you type something in and it *looks* like it's highlighted correctly ***does not*** mean the identifier actually exists in the system. Keep in mind that invalid identifiers revert back to *default*.